# How to fail an MSBuild when content files are missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I've noticed that our cruise control server does not fail the build when content files are missing.

I'd like to fail the build when javascript / graphics files etc are missing. How can I go about validating the project file with the files pulled from svn?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a target to check to make sure that all Content files are physically located on disk and raise an error if this is not the case. Here is such a target

```
<Target Name="ValidateContentFiles">
  <Error Condition="!Exists(%(Content.FullPath))" 
         Text="Missing Content file [%(Content.FullPath)]"/>
</Target>
```

You can make sure that this target is executed everytime by adding it to the InitialTargets attribute on the Project element. For example

```
<Project InitialTargets="ValidateContentFiles"
         ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 3):

You can also add the error condition in *BeforeBuild* Target available in .csproj like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Error Condition="!Exists(%(Content.FullPath))"
Text="Missing Content file [%(Content.FullPath)]"/>
</Target>
```

*BeforeBuild* will always execute when building a project and so you do not require adding the target to InitialTargets attribute of the Project property.